# spring boot Authentication and Authorization Events not triggered

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have Authentication Auditing Support in my application, I followed the following article to implement it.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-authentication-audit

The last time it worked I had the following versions of

```
        <spring.version>5.1.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
```

then in some point, we upgrade spring and spring boot

```
        <spring.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
```

and now the auditEventHappened method no longer breaks when user logins to the application

```
@Component
public class LoginAttemptsLogger {

    @EventListener
    public void auditEventHappened(
      AuditApplicationEvent auditApplicationEvent) {

        AuditEvent auditEvent = auditApplicationEvent.getAuditEvent();
        System.out.println("Principal " + auditEvent.getPrincipal() 
          + " - " + auditEvent.getType());

        WebAuthenticationDetails details = 
          (WebAuthenticationDetails) auditEvent.getData().get("details");
        System.out.println("Remote IP address: "
          + details.getRemoteAddress());
        System.out.println("  Session Id: " + details.getSessionId());
    }
}
```

Hoping that someone had the same issue and was able to solve it .. downgrading the libraries this is not the way to solve it ..

Comment: Have you read [the migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#actuator-http-trace-and-auditing-are-disabled-by-default)? In short those are disabled by default as of 2.2.0 and need to be explicitly enabled as mentioned in said migration guide.

Comment: @M. Deinum honestly, I didn't do the migration so I didn't read the migration guilde, that makes a lot of sense! thank you I try to follow the migration guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in case you are stuck like me, I was able to make it work:

this is the tricky part, I was expecting, that been generation will be something that returns new AuditEventRepository(), but no  AuditEventRepository is an interface and you need to implement custom behavior. so if you are happy with default implementation use `InMemoryAuditEventRepository`

```
@Bean
public InMemoryAuditEventRepository auditEventRepository() throws Exception {
  return new InMemoryAuditEventRepository();
}
```

you will need to turn the audit on in the application.property file

```
management.auditevents.enabled = true
```